# Python : Convert list of strings to floats with empty/none

Tags: python, string, nan, min, is-empty

I have `a = ['1','2','','17']`

I would like to apply a min / max operation on it. I can't use pandas/numpy.

I convert it to a float, however, but I can't convert '' to floats with the float() function. Same thing happens if I have a None rather than a ''.

I never faced this problem in matlab so I'm lost with python.

I can convert it into a float with `[float(i) for i in var if i]`, but I need to keep the same size to work on index later. This method will remove the empty strings, it is not what I want, I need a value (apparently not a None) that I could apply mean/max/min etc on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a function that tries to convert values to floats and returns `None` if it can't, then use list comprehensions to create converted and filtered versions of the list you can use `min`/`max`/... whatever on while keeping the original intact.

```
def try_float(v):
   try:
       return float(v)
   except Exception:
       return None

# Original:
a = ['1', '2', '', '17', None, 'purple', -7, 0]

# Containing floats and Nones:
floaty_a = [try_float(item) for item in a]

# Filter out the Nones:
filtered_a = [item for item in floaty_a if item is not None]

# Compute min/max:
print(min(filtered_a))
print(max(filtered_a))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's similar to what I want (the floaty_a) so I can apply index position later on it

Comment: if you're using Pandas, you can use

df['MyColumn'] = df['MyColumn'].astype(float)

This will take care of None automatically

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar situation. I suggest you replace the `''` with `np.nan`.

```
x = ['1.1', '', '2.3', '2.0']

for i, v in enumerate(x):
    if v == '':
        x[i] = np.nan
    else:
        x[i] = float(v)

print(x)
[1.1, nan, 2.3, 2.0]
```

Curiously, I find out that it works only if `x` is list. It doesn't work with numpy arrays!

Maybe there is a 'comprehension list' way to do that.